# Raid 1 with two hard drives, which hard drive will overwrite the other?

Tags: motherboard, raid, raid-1, hardware-raid

I have two hard drives in a raid-1 volume that Windows 7 boots from (let's call them harddrive-a and harddrive-b). I got a third harddrive-c so that I could install Linux.

To protect my Windows install from not working or somehow losing all the data, I removed harddrive-a ,one of the mirrored drives, before installing Linux.

I was able to successfully install Linux on the new drive and also boot into Windows.

When I plug in harddrive-a, the raid-1 array will rebuild. **What drive will be the golden copy (I.e the harddrive that is not overwritten) harddrive-a or harddrive-b? How does the raid controller determine which drive is the golden copy?**

Note: raid is hardware and provided by motherboard. If the exact motherboard or raid controller is needed I can look it up.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove a drive from a RAID array, the array begins to run in a degraded state.  The active drive(s) in a RAID array (as you said harddrive-b) begin to constitute the "golden copy".  When you add harddrive-a back to the degraded array, harddrive-a will be synced with the data in the active array.

Comment: I concur. The disconnected drive will be rebuilt from the one that was alive at the time of the disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Logically I think.
If you plug in again the hard disk you also need to reconfigure it in the raid controller as new disk to the existing array.
Thus data will be since from the existing disk in array to the one you just plug in.